# Insert item into unordered list at a given index with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have:

```
<ul>

<li>Cthulhu</li>
<li>Godzilla</li>
<li>King Kong</li>

</ul>
```

I want to insert `<li>Pink Panther</li>` after Godzilla (index 2). How can I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method with the [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector:

```
$("ul li:eq(1)").after($("<li>Pink Panther</li>"));
```

Note that, since `:eq()` is zero-based, Godzilla has index 1 instead of 2.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) and [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) like this:

```
$('#ul_id li:eq(1)').after('<li>Pink Panther</li>');
```

For `eq` index starts from `0` so `1` corresponds to `<li>Godzilla</li>`.

Answer (score 4):

`$('ul').eq(1).after($('<li>Pink Panther</li'));` btw index of Godzilla is 1 since indexing starts with 0 :)

Answer (score 2):

You can access the array of LIs via jquery selectors like this:

```
var secondElement = $("ul li")[1];
$(secondElement).after("<li>New element!</li>");
```

This will produce the following HTML:

```
<ul>

<li>Cthulhu</li>
<li>Godzilla</li>
<li>New element!</li>
<li>King Kong</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [nth child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/7582w/) is an example